# Status date changed while the status remain ``Decision in process"

Tags: paper-submission, journal-workflow

I have submitted a paper in an Elsevier Journal. Two days after submission, the status changed to with editor. After 15 days, the status date changed with the same status. After ten days, the status changed to the decision in process. Recently, after a week, the status date changed with the same status ``Decision in process". What does that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The status date changes whenever someone does something to the paper. This often, but not always, changes the status.

An example of how the status date might change but the status remains as "decision in progress" is if the journal is set up so that the editorial board member makes a decision, the decision is forwarded to the editor-in-chief, and the editor-in-chief makes the final decision. In this case the board member making a decision would update the status date, but the status remains as "decision in progress" until the editor-in-chief makes the final decision.